# Less Contrast resulting CSS issue

Tags: css, less, contrast

It might be I don't understand the Less contrast function correctly but I don't seem to get the results I would expect.
I am trying to get a contrasting color for buttons on a (dark) colored background.

I did some testing and what it comes down to is this:

```
a {
    &.a {
        color: contrast(#222222, #111111, #555555);
    }
    &.b {
        color: contrast(#333333, #111111, #555555);
    }
    &.c {
        color: contrast(#444444, #111111, #555555);
    }
    &.d {
        color: contrast(#555555, #111111, #555555);
    }
    &.e {
        color: contrast(#666666, #111111, #555555);
    }
}
```

I would expect the contrast function to switch from #111 to #555 somewhere, but I always get #555 as a result.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Timo88/pen/Xoxyez

Comment: Well, it will switch approximately at `#bbb`. This is for sure is awkward and to understand why it is that way I'm afraid you need to consult various `contrast` related discussions at the Less dev repo to understand why: e.g. [1](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2743#issuecomment-161316573), [2](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2906) etc. (In short it's been talked about its very questionable behaviour for years but each time an improvement was proposed/implemented there came people and ask to revert the older weird way back to not break their existing projects).

Comment: Note also that CodePen uses (probably not even latest) Less v2 while Less docs describe v3.

Comment: OK thanks. I read some of those, but did not understand this was the issue I experienced. Pretty weird behavior as you noted. I guess I'll have to convert scss then.. :-( BTW, according to this https://codepen.io/versions/ codepen uses Less V 3.8.1